# Fold from Map[String,List[Int]] to Map[String,Int]

Tags: scala

I'm fairly new to Scala and functional approaches in general. I have a Map that looks something like this:

```
val myMap: Map[String, List[Int]]
```

I want to end up something that maps the key to the total of the associated list:

```
val totalsMap: Map[String, Int]
```

My initial hunch was to use a for comprehension:

```
val totalsMap = for (kvPair <- myMap) {
    kvPair._2.foldLeft(0)(_+_)
}
```

But I have no idea what I would put in the yield() clause in order to get a map out of the for comprehension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapValues` would be more suited for this case:

```
val m = Map[String, List[Int]]("a" -> List(1,2,3), "b" -> List(4,5,6))

m.mapValues(_.foldLeft(0)(_+_))

res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 6, b -> 15)
```

Or without `foldLeft`:

```
m.mapValues(_.sum)
```

Comment: Thanks! Somehow I missed this function in the Map documentation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use mapValues for this,

```
val totalMap = myMap.mapValues(_.sum)
```

But mapValues will recalculate the sum every time you get a key from the Map. e.g. If you do totalMap("a") multiple times, it will recalculate the sum each time.

If you don't want this, you should use

```
val totalMap = myMap map { 
  case (k, v) => k -> v.sum
}
```

Comment: It will. You can check the behaviour here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/MapLike.scala#L244-257
    def get(key: A) = self.get(key).map(f)

Comment: I was not aware of this.  Is there any way to force evaluation of a "view"?  I suppose you just construct a new collection instance from it?

Comment: You can force evaluation by using val totalMap = myMap.mapValues(_.sum).view.force

Comment: @ntn does that mean that if I access the view multiple times it will not be re-calculated if I use view.force?

Comment: +1 Any answer saying mapValues must mention that it is a view!  They wrote a whole book about it.  http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-037

Answer (score 1):

```
val m = Map("hello" -> Seq(1, 1, 1, 1), "world" -> Seq(1, 1))
for ((k, v) <- m) yield (k, v.sum)
```

yields

```
Map(hello -> 4, world -> 2)`
```

The for comprehension will return whatever monadic type you give it. In this case, `m` is a `Map`, so that's what's going to come out. The `yield` must return a tuple. The first element (which becomes the key in each `Map` entry) is the word you're counting, and the second element (you guessed it, the value in each `Map` entry) becomes the sum of the original sequence of counts.

Comment: Ah, thanks for giving me a better feel for how the syntax of for works. Unfortunately reduce is not an option for me because my actual use case involves a List[object_containing_an_int_that_needs_to_be_unboxed] but I didn't mention that in the question so that's my fault not yours!

Comment: How about "reduce(_.getMyInt + _.getMyInt)"

Comment: ah, yes, well, you can replace .reduce with .foldLeft(0). In any case, `mapValues` looks like a simpler option.